# create variable that takes 1 if it's negative and 0 otherwise

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, boolean, conditional-statements

I want to create a variable X from another variable Y that takes 1 if Y is negative and 0 if Y is positive. I did  `ifelse(Y[Y<0],1,0)` but it only shows 1 if Y[Y<0] but not 0 when Y>=0.

Comment: Just do `ifelse(Y < 0, 1, 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's atest sequence:

```
> Y=seq(-5,5,1)
> Y
 [1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5
```

this is your test in your `ifelse` statement.

```
> Y[Y<0]
[1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1
```

which doesn'tt really mean much,

This is what you probably mean:

```
> ifelse(Y<0,1,0)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: FWIW, `as.integer(Y < 0)` will give the same answer and has a bit less overhead.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Justin's comment in Stephen's answer:

```
Rgames> library(microbenchmark)
Rgames> negone <-function(x) ifelse(x<0,1,0)
Rgames> negtwo <-function(x) as.integer(x<0)
Rgames> longfoo <- -1e6:1e6
Rgames> microbenchmark(negone(longfoo),negtwo(longfoo),times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
            expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
 negone(longfoo) 602.49903 607.36539 616.70490 662.40269 819.8965    10
 negtwo(longfoo)  17.06902  17.55908  20.99846  24.52379  26.0333    10
```